# R - How to remove NAs when using ASSIGN with a FOR LOOP?

Tags: r

I have some code which imports a data frame (keywordsDF), and whilst using a FOR LOOP, it (by using the colnames), creates new variables depending on how many columns there are in it:

```
keywordsDF = read_excel("//Users//n//Desktop//Keywords.xlsx")

keywordList = colnames(keywordsDF)

for (i in seq_along(keywordList)) {
  assign(keywordList[i], keywordsDF[keywordList[i]])
}
```

This all works fine. However, as the columns are of a different length, it imports NAs into the data.

I would normally remove those NAs for each column like:

`consumption = keywordsDF$Consumption[!is.na(keywordsDF$Consumption)]`

But I am not sure how to do it in the FOR LOOP (where I don't know the column names). I.e. where do I put the `!is.na`? As nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `keywordsDF[[keywordList[i]]]` any place you would use `keywordsDF$Consumption`, so

```
# spaced to make the substitution line up
consumption =          keywordsDF$Consumption      [!is.na( keywordsDF$Consumption       )]
assign(keywordList[i], keywordsDF[[keywordList[i]]][!is.na( keywordsDF[[keywordList[i]]] )]
```

But I'd encourage you not to use `assign` like this... a list might be nicer like `kw_no_na = lapply(keywordsDF[keywordList], na.omit)`, then use `kw_no_na$consumption` or `kw_no_na[["consumption"]]`.

Comment: That is super helpful. I was just thinking how I would refer to the n of columns later, but this works perfectly as I can iterate through the index of the list. Super, thank you! :D

Comment: As an FYI, if you didn't know about `na.omit`, you could still use `lapply` with an anonymous function: `lapply(keywordsDF[keywordList], function(x) x[!is.na(x)])`

Comment: Thank you. I like na.omit. Much tidier! Glad to have picked it up!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `na.omit()` ?

```r
for (i in seq_along(keywordList)) {
  assign(keywordList[i], na.omit(keywordsDF[keywordList[i]]))
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you Jim_FRL. Sounds stupid, but I did not know about na.omit, and didn't come up in my Google solutions for a solution to a problem. Thank you!